# ReactJS: Load different view upon Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have learned the basics of ReactJS, and now I want to try it out what I have learned. Therefore I am building this small application to put my learning into practice. I have added below two images. Where I have several buttons in my Home view (1st image). And when buttons are clicked I would like to go to a different view (the 2nd image) where it has a different layout.

I want to know whether this is achievable through ReactJS.

I have used `react-router-dom`, but what it does is it adds the content of the button 1 view to the end of the  home page view. Below is the code I have used.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid vh-100">
      <HomePage />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomePage View

```
import { useNavigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Service1 from './Service1';

function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToService1 = () => {
    navigate('/service1');
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 vh-100 bg-danger">
      </div>

      <div className="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 vh-100 bg-warning">
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success" onClick={navigateToService1}>Service1</button>
      </div>        
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/service1" element={<Service1 />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Below is the Button 1 view (or the service 1 view in here)

```
function Service1() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
        <h1>This is Service1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Service1;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code currently is ***unconditionally*** rendering the `HomePage` component, and *then* all the routes below it. Move the routes into `App` and render `HomePage` also on its own route.

App

```
function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid vh-100">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/service1" element={<Service1 />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

HomePage

```
function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToService1 = () => {
    navigate('/service1');
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 vh-100 bg-danger">
      </div>

      <div className="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 vh-100 bg-warning">
        <button
          className="btn btn-lg btn-success"
          onClick={navigateToService1}
        >
          Service1
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code correction. Would you mind to explain this to me please ? I think I was lacking some basic knowledge in routing as I think

Comment: @Cham Sure, was there a specific part that I could help clear up?

Comment: @drew-resse: I would like to know more about the routing bit. If you could explain or redirect me to a proper documentation, that would be great

Comment: @Cham If you are *just* getting starting in learning client-side routing then it's a subject that is a bit heavy for stackoverflow. I'd recommend starting with the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview) and work through the Getting Started section. The über high-level view is that `react-router` applies [conditional rendering](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering) of content where the conditions are based on matching routes to the current URL, and handling the navigation between managed routes.